# Swagger POST generated parameter body override

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a sample object which is referenced by swagger to create a POST endpoint in my documentation.

I then use the documentation to generate a client for testing. However, the API works slightly differently then how the object is directly presented. I want to override the POST body parameter type of the created model in the documentation from a service type to a string (a reference string to the service). I've included the referenced object below.

```
@Entity
public class ServiceType {

    private String id;
    private Service service;
    private String type;

    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

The body is generate as:

```
{
  "createdDate": "2019-03-12T15:18:22.568Z",
  "id": "string",
  "service": {
    "createdDate": "2019-03-12T15:18:22.568Z",
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "routingKey": "string",
    "updatedBy": "string",
    "updatedDate": "2019-03-12T15:18:22.569Z"
  },
  "type": "string",
  "updatedBy": "string",
  "updatedDate": "2019-03-12T15:18:22.569Z"
}
```

But I want it to be in the format:

```
{
  "createdDate": "2019-03-12T15:18:22.568Z",
  "id": "string",
  "service": "string",
  "type": "string",
  "updatedBy": "string",
  "updatedDate": "2019-03-12T15:18:22.569Z"
}
```

Not sure if this is possible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`@ApiModel`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/index.html?com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModel.html) and [`@ApiModelProperty`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.3.12/apidocs/index.html?com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html) annotations to override the default data type for a field. Note that the data type must be a fully-qualified type name (such as `java.lang.String`). For more information, see [Overriding Property Datatypes](https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#overriding-property-datatypes).

```
@Entity
@ApiModel
public class ServiceType {

    private String id;

    @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "java.lang.String")
    private Service service;
    private String type;

    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to do anything to my swagger configuration class to enable the application of the property type? When I make the changes the documentation remains the same for some reason. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: @jkollin Try using `java.lang.String` instead of `string` for the data type. Data type overrides must be fully qualified. For more information, see https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#overriding-property-datatypes. (I've updated the answer above.)

Comment: Yup, that did it! Thanks